# UIScrollView covers UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, iboutlet

I have created a `UIScrollView` and am now trying to place a `UIButton` over the scroll view. However when I build and run the application the scroll view still works fine but I cannot see the `UIButton`.

I link the `UIButton IBOutlet` inside the interface builder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;

    backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"auckland-300.jpg"]];

    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"249a-134206f1d00-1342071f5d9.ImgPlayerAUCKLAND.png"]];

    // Note here you should size the container view appropriately and layout backgroundImage and image accordingly.
    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,601,601)];
    playButton = [[UIButton alloc] init]; //test button cannot see it.
    [containerView addSubview:backgroundImage];
    [containerView addSubview:image];

    scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];
    self.view = scrollView;    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to add UIButton *in* scrollView or *above* scrollView?

Comment: above the scrollview so i can still pinch to zoom and scroll without effecting the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems ok. But I think the reason you are not able to see the button `playButton` is  because you are not adding it to the `view` itself.

Dont you need to do this ?  `[containerView addSubview:playButton];`

To help you out, here's what I do for debugging -

> UIView implements a useful description method. In addition, it
>   implements a recursiveDescription method that you can call to get a
>   summary of an entire view hierarchy.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [controller.view recursiveDescription]);
```

Comment: Hrmm.. still acting funny. I truest to use the slog but for an issue with controller.. so looking into that now.

Comment: Okay got it to work with a Programatically designed button however. when I put it into the same view it zooms also.. So now I'm trying to figure out how to get it to appear above.. maybe with another view or something.

Comment: yes that could work. Also if this answer has helped please consider accepting this answer... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The button is probably in the nib that you linked the controllers view to, right? By assigning the scrollview to the view, you remove the view from
The nib from the controller, that's why you can't see te button or press it.

You can either place the button in the scrollview or you add both scrollView and thenthe playButton as subviews of self.view.

Maybe you want to rethink your design tho.
Placing a button over a scrollview doesn't really seem like good practice to me.

Comment: okay cool thanks, Currently the button is for testing later I want to have a transparent image for play and stop to play an animation inside the scrollview etc.